# Update Stunnel on CentOS

Tags: linux, service, centos, stunnel

I connect to a service using stunnel version 4.29, the providers of this service disabled connection via stunnel 4.29. This now requires i update my stunnel from the WHM.

i updated using

```
  yum update stunnel
 Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Update Process
 Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
  * base: repos.lax.quadranet.com
 * extras: dallas.tx.mirror.xygenhosting.com
* updates: dallas.tx.mirror.xygenhosting.com
No Packages marked for Update
```

and i get the response - No Packages marked for Update

Please does anyone know how i can update to stunnel 5.29?

Comment: If there isn't a package for it in the official repositories and the epel and IUS repositories don't have it either then you probably need to build it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no stunnel version 5.29 https://www.stunnel.org/downloads.html

CentOS 7 has stunnel-4.56 :     stunnel-4.56-4.el7.**src**.rpm

```
$ rpmbuild -bb stunnel.spec
```

CentOS 6 package : stunnel-4.56-4.el6.x86_64.rpm

Download link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSEFrVE1iNE81VzQ/view?usp=sharing